# Can twilio quick start sdk be used for a full fledged application or it is just for learning purpose?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to develop a web application where users will be able to schedule a video call between them. I want to use twilio. I would like to know if the quickstart app of twilio can be used for it or it is just for learning purpose? If quickstart app can be used for this. How many group of (group of 2 users) can it support?

Comment: Quickstart app is there to get you basic understanding, you can explore with [Video Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video). And you can have upto [50 users](https://www.twilio.com/video/pricing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twilio Quickstart applications (in this case Programmable Video Quickstart) are a great way for developers to familiarize themselves with Twilio's SDK's and the various methods and properties. It helps with the understanding and creation of common capabilities.

Additionally, the Programmable Video Quickstart has an /examples route, which provides code snippets on further extending out functionality based on your particular use case.

Programmable Video has 3 different room types and their capabilities are best explained at the link below. The scaling is handled by Twilio, so that should not be an issue. If using Peer-to-Peer rooms, Twilio only handles the signaling and the media goes directly between the two Video end-points.

For your use case, Peer-to-Peer or Small Group Rooms could be viable based on the [feature set](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/understanding-video-rooms#comparing-room-types) you are looking for.

[Understanding Video Rooms](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/understanding-video-rooms)